# Meteor+ Blaze : If else block in spacebars template not executing for the second time

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars, meteor-helper

The objective is to show buttons dynamically on click event. On click of edit button, save and cancel buttons are displayed. On click of cancel button, the edit button should be displayed back which is not working. I am using session in helper.

`template.html`

```
<head>
    <title>ifelse</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

    {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
    {{isEdit}}

    {{#if isEdit}}
        <div class="saveCancelBtnBarLogic">
            <button class="button">Save</button>
            <button class="cancelEditLogic button">Cancel</button>
        </div>
        {{else}}
        <button class="editDishButtonLogic button">Edit</button>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

`template.js`

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

    Template.hello.events({
        "click .editDishButtonLogic": function(event, template) {
            console.log("edit true");

            Session.set("isEditSession", "true");
        }

    });

    Template.hello.events({
        "click .cancelEditLogic": function(event, template) {
            console.log("edit false");
            Session.set("isEditSession", "false");
        }
    });

    Template.hello.helpers({
        isEdit: function() {
            console.log("edit helper : " + Session.get("isEditSession"));
            return Session.get("isEditSession");
        }
    });
}
```

The project is also deployed @ http://ifelse.meteor.com for reference.

Comment: this is because changing `isEdit`doesn't re-render the template. Look into [template_autorun](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_autorun) and user `reactive variables` to re render the template when the session variable updates.

Comment: @guranjan-singh Not sure why it works for the first time. On clicking edit, save and cancel buttons are displayed using the same logic and session variable. However, on click of cancel button it does not work. Also, session variables are reactive. This example does not involve user variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved:

Changed the below line:
`Session.set("isEditSession", "false");`

to so:

`Session.set("isEditSession", false);`

false is a boolean here - notice that false is not in quotes anymore. Thanks to benjick who answered it here @ https://forums.meteor.com/t/if-else-block-in-spacebars-template-not-executing-for-the-second-time/8388/2

Comment: Good spotting - I was just about to post that if I did this in the console it would work:  
`Session.set("isEditSession", true);
  Session.set("isEditSession", false);`  
  
So it is definitely reactive, as it should be.  It's just that the string "false" is actually "truthy" (as in it acts like a "true" value) which is why "isEdit" was always true once the session variable had been set.

Comment: You're right. My first impression (in the comments) was wrong. String value is always true. It works the first time because at that time session variable isn't set and its `undefined` which translates to false.